# Dynamic positioning based on screen width and window width only

Tags: html, css, dynamic

I've trawled through various 'solved' dynamic positioning queries but cannot find anything that helps.
I have the following page...

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +-----------+ +------------------+ +------------------+ +-----------+ |
| |   IMG 1   | |                  | |                  | |   IMG 4   | |
| | width:20% | | IMG 2, width:30% | | IMG 3, width:30% | | width:20% | |
| |  aspect   | | aspect ratio 4:3 | | aspect ratio 4:3 | |  aspect   | |
| |  ratio    | |                  | |                  | |  ratio    | |
| |   3:4     | +------------------+ +------------------+ |   3:4     | |
| |           |                                           |           | |
| +-----------+                                           +-----------+ |
| +-----------+                                           +-----------+ |
| |   IMG 5   |                                           |   IMG 6   | |
| | width:20% |                                           | width:20% | |
| |  aspect   |                                           |  aspect   | |
| |  ratio    |                                           |  ratio    | |
| |   3:4     |                                           |   3:4     | |
| |           |                                           |           | |
| +-----------+                                           +-----------+ |
| +-----------+                                           +-----------+ |
| |   IMG 7   |                                           |   IMG 8   | |
| | width:20% |                                           | width:20% | |
| |  aspect   |                                           |  aspect   | |
| |  ratio    |                                           |  ratio    | |
| |   3:4     |                                           |   3:4     | |
| |           |                                           |           | |
| +-----------+                                           +-----------+ |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

(1) I want the images to resize based on the window width only, i.e. if the user resizes the window vertically I don't want the images resized.
(2) Also, I only want this resizing to happen until the window is 50% of the screen width, then they will remain the same size, i.e. IMG 1 width would remain at 10% of the screen width.

I can achieve (1) for the top row. The problem is for IMGs 5 -8 since the 'top' value is calculated from the window height.

Is there some way I can achieve what I want dynamically? 
I can't use calc() since it bases its result for top based on window height.
Also, there appears to be no CSS for screen.width and JS is not dynamic for resizing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. (further images are below might help explain what I mean)

magic²

Full Screen

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +-----------+ +------------------+ +------------------+ +-----------+ |
| |   IMG 1   | |                  | |                  | |   IMG 4   | |
| | width:20% | | IMG 2, width:30% | | IMG 3, width:30% | | width:20% | |
| |  aspect   | | aspect ratio 4:3 | | aspect ratio 4:3 | |  aspect   | |
| |  ratio    | |                  | |                  | |  ratio    | |
| |   3:4     | +------------------+ +------------------+ |   3:4     | |
| |           |                                           |           | |
| +-----------+                                           +-----------+ |
| +-----------+                                           +-----------+ |
| |   IMG 5   |                                           |   IMG 6   | |
| | width:20% |                                           | width:20% | |
| |  aspect   |                                           |  aspect   | |
| |  ratio    |                                           |  ratio    | |
| |   3:4     |                                           |   3:4     | |
| |           |                                           |           | |
| +-----------+                                           +-----------+ |
| +-----------+                                           +-----------+ |
| |   IMG 7   |                                           |   IMG 8   | |
| | width:20% |                                           | width:20% | |
| |  aspect   |                                           |  aspect   | |
| |  ratio    |                                           |  ratio    | |
| |   3:4     |                                           |   3:4     | |
| |           |                                           |           | |
| +-----------+                                           +-----------+ |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

width: 50% height:100%

```
+-------------------------------------------+
| +------+ +---------+ +---------+ +------+ |
| |IMG 1 | |  IMG 2  | |  IMG 3  | |IMG 4 | |
| |      | |         | |         | |      | |
| |      | +---------+ +---------+ |      | |
| +------+                         +------+ |
| +------+                         +------+ |
| |IMG 5 |                         |IMG 6 | |
| |      |                         |      | |
| |      |                         |      | |
| +------+                         +------+ |
| +------+                         +------+ |
| |IMG 7 |                         |IMG 8 | |
| |      |                         |      | |
| |      |                         |      | |
| +------+                         +------+ |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

width: 50% height: 50%

```
+-------------------------------------------+
| +------+ +---------+ +---------+ +------+ |
| |IMG 1 | |  IMG 2  | |  IMG 3  | |IMG 4 | |
| |      | |         | |         | |      | |
| |      | +---------+ +---------+ |      | |
| +------+                         +------+ |
| +------+                         +------+ |
| |IMG 5 |                         |IMG 6 | |
| |      |                         |      | |
| |      |                         |      | |
| +------+                         +------+ |
| +------+                         +------+ |
| |IMG 7 |                         |IMG 8 | |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

width: 33% height: 50%

```
+-------------------------+
| +------+ +---------+ +--|
| |IMG 1 | |  IMG 2  | |  |
| |      | |         | |  |
| |      | +---------+ +--|
| +------+                |
| +------+                |
| |IMG 5 |                |
| |      |                |
| |      |                |
| +------+                |
| +------+                |
| |IMG 7 |                |
+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Thanks Pauline. I have tried *everything* that I can think of in CSS, i.e. different positions styles (absolute, fixed etc). My problem is not being able to dynamically calculate using screen.width. I could post any\all code I have tried but since none of them do what I require I didn't see the point. I am not looking for anyone to code this for me, I was just hoping for suggestions like the vh vw offered below. There is probably tons of CSS that I don't know where someone might just pop up and say "you need to use ???? property".

Answer (score 1):

So this method isn't perfect, but in order to do this you need a value that represents the size of the screen without using %. In CSS there are 2 values you can use, these are vw and vh, for your purposes you will want vw for the width of the viewport.

vw is equal to the viewport width / 100

vh is equal to the viewport height / 100

These values are dynamic, if the window is resized so are these, so in order to keep constant proportions you can use either vw or vh, here's an example.

```css
.square
{
  width: 2vw;
  height: 2vw;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  top: 5vh;
  left: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
</div>
```

You could do more advanced calculations by working out the aspect ratio of the screen, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately vh and vw are based on the initial containing block, not the screen size, so seem to offer no advantage over %

Comment: So just use vw for everything, if you resize the window vertically vw doesn't change, only if you resize it horizontally and it updates dynamically with the window width, I don't see why you couldn't use that?

Comment: Hi again, you're right that this works, but not for the part where I don't want images to resize if the window.width < (screen.width/2). Not sure if what I'm trying to do can be done in pure html\CSS. I know nothing about jquery but is seems to come up a lot in my searched for an answer so I'll take a deeper look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Found what I required, it was the javascript onresize event.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onresize="myFunction()">
<span id="demo"><img src="img1.jpg" width="20%"></span>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    if (window.innerWidth > (screen.width/2))
    {
        var txt = "<img src='img1.jpg' width='20%'>";
    } else {
        var txt = "<img src='img1.jpg' width='";
        txt = txt + screen.width/10;
        txt = txt + "'>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This resizes the image @ 20% window.innerWidth until window.innerWidth <= screen.width, then the image size remains the same @ 10% screen.width.